# active div text to input field

Tags: jquery, forms

I have an image slider which appends a class="active" when it is the current slider. i'm trying to put the image's caption into an input field but couldn't.

current code is:

```
<div class="slide">
  <div class="active"><!-- The active class is only appended -->
  <div class="caption>Some text</div>
  </div>
  <div>
  <div class="caption">Moremore</div>
  </div>
</div>

<input type="text" name="magic" value="">

$("input[name=magic]").val($(".caption").text());
```

The above almost works but it just displays all the text inside all the caption classes.

So, for the above, the input field would have

```
Some textmoremore
```

Thanks in advance!

V

Comment: So give the div whose text you actually want and Id and use that as a selector instead of a class

Comment: the active div with the caption call. but when you click <next> or <previous> in the slide, the active class moves to another div, so the caption of that newly active div should be in the input field

Answer (score 0):

Until better solutions are found, this works:

```
$('input[name="magic"]').val(
    $(".slide .active .caption").text()
);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xukw7f3y/1/)

Comment: thanks, but this is in an image slider though, where the class is only appended once <next><previous> the slide. the above, as all the other solutions so far, only works when the active class is actually coded into the div.

Comment: Hm... Why do you say that? I made this new example that (1) changes the class, then (2) gets the right input from the new div: http://jsfiddle.net/xukw7f3y/3/

Comment: ps. You should use a callback on the slider. So that the $(input ...) is called when ever the slider changes. Otherwise it only works the first time.

Comment: I don't know what slider you're using to show you an example. (I made this up: http://jsfiddle.net/xukw7f3y/6/) Some jquery or bootstrap sliders have callback functions that you can customize. See:  http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/ or http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ If you use them, you can change the options to include a customized function on a certain event (like "scroll")

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to get only "Some text" in the input field?

Just use `$("input[name=magic]").val($(".active .caption").text());`

This will only show the text inside the div with the class `caption` inside a div with the class `active`.

See [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gagoL9bs/)

Comment: thanks, but this is in an image slider though, where the class is only appended once <next><previous> the slide. the above, as all the other solutions so far, only works when the active class is actually coded into the div.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('input[name="magic"]').val(
    $(".active").find(".caption").text()
);
```

You need to be targeting the caption of the active div, not all captions.

Comment: thanks, but this is in an image slider though, where the class is only appended once <next><previous> the slide. the above, as all the other solutions so far, only works when the active class is actually coded into the div.